# Does / Will AKS support spreading pods across update domains?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

According to [this](https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/05/15/more-reliable-replica-sets-in-aks-part-1/) article (April 2018) AKS is capable of intelligently placing pods across fault domains when running in an availability set, but it does not consider update domains yet. Will update domains be used to place pods in AKS anytime soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already does this automatically when you setup your cluster. Your nodes are placed into an availability set and in that availability set they are placed into separate fault domains and update domains.

[image]

Comment: Are pods guaranteed to always be in spread across update domains? My impression was that the author of the article I referenced tested this. He saw after launching many times that sometimes pods are spread across update domains as you pointed out, but also sometimes you get unlucky and they are not.

Comment: Whenever an Availability set is in place the Azure Platform will ensure that all VMs are placed in separate update and fault domains. I have not ran across a time when they have been setup in this manner but it did not happen. I have seen times where even in an AV set there was a really unlucky time where both fault domains went down at the same time due to an outage. But regardless, the VMs were placed on separate update and fault domains.

Comment: For those reading over this older issue, K8s now supports topology spread constraints which can be used to ensure an even schedule over fault domains: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#example-multiple-topologyspreadconstraints